# append elements from multidimensional array to html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am designing a category system with jquery where I can insert values in a multidimensional array then use jquery to append them to some html page. I ran to a problem where I have to update the code every time I add more elements to my array.

var arr = [];

```
arr =
{
"a":{
      "d":"value",
      "e":"value",
      "f":"value",
      "g":{"some value":[1, 2, 3]}
    },
"b":{
    "value1":"value",
    "value2":{"aaa":{"sss": "ddd"}, "bbb":{"eee": "ddd"}},
    "value3":"value vvv"
    },
"c":[1, 2, 3]
};
```

I want to append the elements of the array to an html page so the results would look like this:

```
-a
--d
---value
--e
---value
--f
---value
--g
---some value
----1
----2
----3
-b
--value1
---value
--value2
---aaa
----sss
----ddd
---bbb
----eee
----ddd
--value3
---value vvv
-c
--1
--2
--3
```

I want to write a series of $.each statements to go through any multidimensional array (with x number of levels) and append its elements as shown above. The problem I am running into is that I am getting [object Object] values and I understand why, but I need to fetch and append all of the elements. I am not sure how to write the $.each statements.

this is what I tried

```
$.each(arr, function(idx, obj){ 
    $("#categories").append("--"+obj+"<br>");
    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
        $("#categories").append("--"+value+"<br>");
         //keep going with the each statements and check if the elements are objects

    });
});
```

Sorry For my English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that does this for you - I've re-laid out your return slightly because it makes little sense to have the value returned below the string indented further.  You can't then tell if it's a key or a value.

```
var indent = "";

function myFunction(obj) {

    indent += '-';

    for (var key in obj) {

        x = obj[key];

        if ($.isPlainObject(x)) {
            $('#categories').append(indent + key + '<br />');
            myFunction(x);
        } else {
            $('#categories').append(indent + key + '<br />');
            if (typeof x === 'object') {
                for (var key in x) {
                    $('#categories').append(indent + '-' + x[key] + '<br />');
                }
            } else {
                $('#categories').append(indent + '-' + x + '<br />');
            }
        }
    }

    indent = indent.substring(0, indent.length - 1);
}

myFunction(arr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8u53K/1/

Comment: This worked grate but I need the results exactly as I have in the example I made. You don't need to worry about the "-".

Answer (score 1):

After several minutes I did it.

```
$.each(arr, function(idx, obj){ 
$("#categories").append("-"+idx+"<br>");
for(var i in obj)
{
    if (typeof (obj[i])!='number')
          $("#categories").append("--"+i+"<br>");
    if(typeof (obj[i])==='object')
    {
        for(var j in obj[i])
        {
            $("#categories").append("---"+j+"<br>");
            var len =obj[i][j].length;
            if(typeof len=='undefined')
            {
                for (var m in obj[i][j])
                    $("#categories").append("----"+m+"<br>");
                $("#categories").append("----"+obj[i][j][m]+"<br>");
            }
            else
            {
                for(var k=0;k<obj[i][j].length;k++)
                {
                   $("#categories").append("----"+obj[i][j][k]+"<br>");
                }
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
    $("#categories").append("---"+obj[i]+"<br>");
    }
}

});
```

here is an example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HuSMQ/)

Comment: This isn't recursive so would break if any more levels were required.  Not with the OP asked for but it may as well be made to be versatile.

Comment: I mean if you needed more than 4 levels of indents.